# Regular expression for replacing integers followed by underscore in a string in php

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I am new to regular expressions in php.

I am trying to replace values something like

> 101_1
>  
>   102_2
>   103_3

to word "custom values" in my strings

I have tried many combinations but could not find solution. Here is the code I think should work according to documentation of regular expressions help available on internet

```
$result = str_replace('[1-6]*_1', "custom values", $string);
```

Remember these values come in between the string, nor in start neither in end of string.

Comment: Are the `xxx_x` numbers always the same length/format?

Comment: `[1-6]` means a digit between `1` and `6`. Now guess what should be used instead of `1` at the end

Comment: Oh, I get it ... You're using the wrong function. You should be using `preg_replace()`

Comment: @HamZa, Thanks — I switch between two many regexes sometimes to remember the escapes, which is kind of important. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression doesn't work because it is not capturing the 0 in [1-6].

Assuming you always have an underscore between one or more digits, use:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\d+_\d+/', "custom values", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something such as this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\d{3}_\d/', "custom values", $string);
```

it captures the first three digits followed by the underscore and then another digit.

Answer (score 1):

use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) instead of str_replace

```
preg_replace('/[0-6]{1,3}_[1-3]/', 'custom values', $string);
```